# Doesn't JavaScript support closures with local variables?

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

I am very puzzled about this code:

```
var closures = [];
function create() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    closures[i] = function() {
      alert("i = " + i);
    };
  }
}

function run() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    closures[i]();
  }
}

create();
run();
```

From my understanding it should print `0,1,2,3,4` (isn't this the concept of closures?).

Instead it prints `5,5,5,5,5`.

I tried Rhino and Firefox.
Could someone explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Fixed Jon's answer by adding an additional anonymous function:

```
function create() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    closures[i] = (function(tmp) {
        return function() {
          alert("i = " + tmp);
        };
    })(i);
  }
}
```

The explanation is that JavaScript's scopes are function-level, not block-level, and creating a closure just means that the enclosing scope gets added to the lexical environment of the enclosed function.

After the loop terminates, the function-level variable `i` has the value `5`, and that's what the inner function 'sees'.

---

As a side note: you should beware of unnecessary function object creation, espacially in loops; it's inefficient, and if DOM objects are involved, it's easy to create circular references and therefore introduce memory leaks in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 9):

I think this might be what you want:

```
var closures = [];

function createClosure(i) {
    closures[i] = function() {
        alert("i = " + i);
    };
}

function create() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        createClosure(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to have a self-executing lambda wrapping your array push. You also pass i as an argument to that lambda. The value of i inside the self-executing lambda will shadow the value of the original i and everything will work as intended:

```
function create() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) (function(i) {
        closures[i] = function() {
            alert("i = " + i);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Another solution would be to create yet another closure which captures the correct value of i and assigns it to another variable which would "get caught" in the final lambda:

```
function create() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) (function() {
        var x = i;

        closures.push(function() {
            alert("i = " + x);
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: To make the first implementation more clear and understandable, you could use a different parameter name than i to the inner function!

Comment: @Chetan Sastry, I wasn't exactly after that. As you can see, even the placement of the self-executing lambda is weird. As if there was no problem in the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

Yes closures are working here.  Each time you loop the function you are creating grabs the `i`.  Each function you create shares the same `i`.  The problem you are seeing is that since they all share the same `i` they also share the final value of `i` since it is the same captured variable.

**Edit:** [This article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) by Mr. Skeet explains closures in some depth and addresses this issue in particular in a way that is much more informative then I have here.  ***However be careful as the way that Javascript and C# handle closures have some subtle differences.***  Skip to the section called "Comparing capture strategies: complexity vs power" for his explanation on this issue.

Comment: So what would be his fix (I'm curious now too)?

Comment: It's a nice article but it appears that there are some differences in how closures are implemented between C# and Javascript.  This makes the article not as helpful with regards to the OP's question.

Comment: You make a good point - the main thing I wanted to communicate was how multiple closures share a variable.

Comment: @Andrew: It's probably worth explicitly saying in your answer that JavaScript captured variables *don't* work the same way - which is why my attempted fix didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

John Resig's [Learning Advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) explains this and more. It's an interactive presentation that explains a lot about JavaScript, and the examples are fun to read and execute.

It has a chapter about closures, and [this example](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#62) looks a lot like yours.

Here's the broken example:

```
var count = 0; 
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) { 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    assert( i == count++, "Check the value of i." ); 
  }, i * 200); 
}
```

And the fix:

```
var count = 0; 
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) (function(i){ 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    assert( i == count++, "Check the value of i." ); 
  }, i * 200); 
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just defining an inner function, or assigning it to some variable:

```
closures[i] = function() {...
```

does not create a private copy of the whole execution context. The context isn't copied until the nearest outer function is **exiting** (at which point those external variables could be garbage collected, so we'd better grab a copy).

This is why wrapping another function around your inner function works - the middle guy actually executes and exits, cuing the innermost function to save his own copy of the stack.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you should do to achieve your result:

```
<script>
var closures = [];
function create() {  
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        closures[i] = function(number) {      
        alert("i = " + number);   
        };  
    }
}
function run() {  
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        closures[i](i); 
    }
}
create();
run();
</script>
```

Comment: How is this an example of closures at all now?  You're basically just storing functions in the array, then explicitly providing 'i' through the function's arguments.