# How to pass parameter to mousewheel event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  $('#content-scroll' + n).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0) sliderUp(n - 1);
    else if (delta < 0) sliderDown(n - 1);
    return false; // prevent default
  });
  n++;
}
```

I have a problem with this code, variable "n" is not passed right to the mouswheel function which will add mousewheel only to number 9 (last number) and not to all 10 elements.
Can anyone explain how to pass a variable to this function so that it stays?

Answer (score 3):

My take on this using a fully jQuery solution.

```
$("[id^='content-scroll']").mousewheel( function(event,delta) {
     var n = this.id.replace(/content-scroll/,'');
     if (delta > 0)
        sliderUp(n);
     else if (delta < 0)
        sliderDown(n);
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

**EDIT**: Actually, I may even try to figure out a way to pass the actual matching control to the slider* functions, but not knowing what they actually do I have no idea how or if that would work.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine and I get it that mousewheel now gets a n value from it's Id. But can you explain why my solution didn't work, because on every loop another content-scroll element got his mousewheel function.

Comment: I believe it's because what actually happened is that the n in the function created for the event handler got bound to the n in the outer loop -- the actual variable, not the value. When the function is invoked, it uses the last value of the variable, not the value when the function was created.

Comment: @Jeremy's solution works because localN is a new variable created in each interation of the loop.  This variable retains the value of n at each iteration of the loop and binding to it in the function gives you the value at that iteration of the loop.

Comment: I prefer my solution because it only searches the DOM once to find all of the matching elements instead of searching once per element to be found.

Comment: i thought that also but @Jeremy's solution also doesn't work, it also binds n and localN to the last value.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an issue of closures in javascript, the n is actually a reference to the outside n variable.  I believe the following should work instead:

```
for(var n=0;n<10;n++)
{
  var localN = n;
  $('#content-scroll'+n).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0) sliderUp(localN-1);
    else if (delta < 0) sliderDown(localN-1);
    return false; // prevent default
  });

  //is this really needed??
  //n++;
}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work try moving the localN inside the mousewheel(function() {  var localN = n-1; })

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, cause mousewheel always takes the last value of localN or n

Answer (score 2):

This is asked a lot on SO ([case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables)). You need a closure to "trap" the value of `n` in each iteration:

```
for(var n=0;n<10;n++)
{
    (function(n){
        $('#content-scroll'+n).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            if (delta > 0) sliderUp(n-1);
            else if (delta < 0) sliderDown(n-1);
            return false; // prevent default
        });
    })(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your `n` values supposed to go from 0-9 or 1-10?

If it's 0-9, change all `n-1` expressions to just `n`.

If it's 1-10, change the `for` loop to `var n=1,n<=10;n++`, and all `n-1` references to just `n`.

Also, remove the `n++` on the bottom because your `for` loop already increments the value of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the code doesn't work is because the n variable is not evaluated during the loop.

You are creating an anonymous function in the loop that you pass to the `mousewheel` function, so the code in the anonymous function isn't executed until the mouse wheel even occurs. By then the value of the n variable is 10, or perhaps something completely different if you are using the variable anywhere else in the code.

If you instead use the `Function` function to create the function from a string, you can inject the current value of the n variable into the code:

```
for(var n=0; n<10; n++) {

   $('#content-scroll' + n).mousewheel(
      Function('event', 'delta',
         'if (delta > 0) sliderUp(' + (n-1) + ');' +
         'else if (delta < 0) sliderDown(' + (n-1) + ');' +
         'return false; // prevent default'
      )
   );

}
```

However, should it be (n-1)? Should the mousewheel event for the `content-scroll0` element call `sliderup(-1)`?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery specifically allows the passing of event data, which may, or may not, be of use to you in this case:

```
for(var n=0;n<10;n++)
{
  $('#content-scroll'+n).bind('mousewheel', {index:n}, function(event, delta) {
    var innerN = event.data.index;
    if (delta > 0) sliderUp(innerN-1);
    else if (delta < 0) sliderDown(innerN-1);
    return false; // prevent default
  });
}
```