# Erroneous behavior of local variables in closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I am stuck at the following code. At first I'll describe the use-case: The function "addPreset" gets called with an instance of ColorGradient. When calling **this.listController.addItem(...)** a callback function named **onSelect** ist supplied, which gets called everytime the onSelect-event on the listController-item is triggered. What I wanted to do is wrapping the call to **GLab.ColorSlider.applyColorGradient(...)** into a new closure, so that the assigned value of **addPreset's "cg" argument"*** will be "caught" inside it. But it doesn't work.

PROBLEM: Now everytime **addPreset** is called, the value of **cg** (being passed with a call) will override all values that bad been assigned before. However, **this.presetList** holds always correct values (the ones I expected to be caught inside the closure-function. Even inserting an anonymous function for breaking the scope doesn't help.

Please help me. :-)

Thanks, so far

```
function addPreset(cg) {
    if (!(cg instanceof ColorGradient)) {
        throw new TypeError("PresetManager: Cannot add preset; invalid arguments received");
    }

    var newIndex = this.listController.addItem(cg.getName(), {
        onSelect: (function(cg2) {
            return function() {
                // addPreset's scope should now be broken
                GLab.ColorSlider.applyColorGradient(cg2);
                console.log(cg2);
            }
        })(cg)
    });

    this.presetList[newIndex] = cg;
}
```

@bobince: of course you can.

the code snippet above is part of **PresetManager.js** and the listController is an instance of the class **ListWrapper.js**

http://code.assembla.com/kpg/subversion/nodes/GradientLab/lib-js/PresetManager.js
http://code.assembla.com/kpg/subversion/nodes/GradientLab/lib-js/ListWrapper.js

@Matt: **cg is an instance of ColorGradient.** A custom class of myself. Further more, it is assured, that always "valid" values are passed in as cg. (When you'd have a few minutes you can download the whole assembla repo as zip-archive. Unzip and test in FF > 3.5 with Firebug console enabled.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

Answer can be found in this question: [Doesn't JavaScript support closures with local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Someone please correct me if I am wrong, as I am still fairly new to JavaScript closures and scope.  But it would seem to me that the wrapping anonymous function you have is simply there to provide a proper scoped variable/closure for the function it is returning.  Could this be simplified as such?

```
function addPreset(cg) {
            if (!(cg instanceof ColorGradient)) {
                throw new TypeError("PresetManager: Cannot add preset; invalid arguments received");
            }

            var closured = cg;
            var newIndex = this.listController.addItem(cg.getName(), {
                onSelect: function() {
                    // addPreset's scope should now be broken
                    GLab.ColorSlider.applyColorGradient(closured);
                    console.log(closured);
                }
            });

            this.presetList[newIndex] = cg;
        }
```

Comment: That's the crux of the matter. My first version looked like this. But the problem that all **cg** is overridden everytime addPreset is called appeared. Then I supposed that I have to check for closures, to bypass that and introduced an anonymous wrapper-function.

Comment: P.s.: Introducing the variable **closured** is useless, though **var** just adds the variable to the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to tell you, that I finally solved my problem by myself. It cost me almost 2 days (in the sparetime) to puzzling it out, but I think its worth that. At least my code remained elegant and I definitely got the whole thing with closures. Let's have a look:

### My faulty code

Part 1 of 2:

```
function addPreset(cg) {
    if (!(cg instanceof ColorGradient)) {
        throw new TypeError("PresetManager: blablabla");
    }
    // calls the function in Part 2
    var newIndex = this.listController.addItem(cg.getName(), {
        onSelect: (function(cg2) {
            return function() {
                // addPreset's scope should now be broken
                GLab.ColorSlider.applyColorGradient(cg2);
                console.log(cg2);
            }
        })(cg)
    });

    this.presetList[newIndex] = cg;
}
```

Part 2 of 2:

```
// The method being called by this.listController.addItem(..)
function addItem(caption, args) {
    var _this = this,
        currIndex,
        id,
        newItem
        itemSelectCb = (!!args && typeof args.onSelect == "function") ?
                            args.onSelect :
                            undefined;

    currIndex = this.numOfItems;
    id = this.ITEM_ID_PREFIX + currIndex;
    newItem = this.$itemTemplate
        .clone()
        .text(caption)
        .attr("id", id)
        .bind("click", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (typeof itemSelectCb != "undefined") {
                itemSelectCb();
            }    
            _this._onSelect($(".ListWrapperItem").index(this));
        })
        .appendTo(this.$container);

    this.numOfItems = $("." + this.DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS, this.$container).length;

    return currIndex;
}
```

### The fixed code

The bug was in Part 2; when calld jQuery's bind-method for adding an click-event-listener I used an anonymous function (= new closure), **but referenced itemSelectCb** inside; so the anonymous function's **scope stayed "connected" to the one of addItem**. Everytime I called addItem, an other value were assigned toitemSelectCb what lead to the unknown sideeffect, that all references to itemSelect inside previously created anonymous functions are pointing to that value. What meant, that the **last assigned value, had been used by all anonymous function.**

To "break" the scope, all I had to do was to modify the lines of **Part 2** where the event-handler for jQuery's bind was created. The fixed code looks then like this:

```
function addItem(caption, args) {
    var _this = this,
        currIndex,
        id,
        newItem
        itemSelectCb = (!!args && typeof args.onSelect == "function") ?
                            args.onSelect :
                            undefined;

    currIndex = this.numOfItems;
    id = this.ITEM_ID_PREFIX + currIndex;
    newItem = this.$itemTemplate
        .clone()
        .text(caption)
        .attr("id", id)
        .bind("click", (function(itemSelectCb) {    

            return function(e) {                    
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (typeof itemSelectCb != "undefined") {
                    itemSelectCb();
                }    
                _this._onSelect($(".ListWrapperItem").index(this));                    
            }

        })(itemSelectCb))
        .appendTo(this.$container);

    this.numOfItems = $("." + this.DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS, this.$container).length;

    return currIndex;
}
```