# JavaScript DOM references not holding up

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, reference

For some reason ss.transition() does not affect the appropriate DOM elements after ss.goTo() is triggered by an onclick. The ss.transition() call under //Init does work as expected. I assume this is a scope problem. Little help?

```
var ss = {};

ss.goTo = function(i) {
    ss.old = ss.current;
    ss.current = ss.slides[i];
    ss.transition();
}

ss.transition = function() {
    ss.old.style.display = "none";
    ss.current.style.display = "block";
}

// Hooks

ss.div = document.getElementById("slides");
ss.as = ss.div.getElementsByTagName("a");

// References

ss.slides = [];
for (i in ss.as) {
    if (ss.as[i].rel == "slide") {
        ss.slides.push(ss.as[i]);
    }
}
ss.first = ss.slides[0];
ss.last = ss.slides[ss.slides.length-1];

// Init

ss.current = ss.first;
ss.old = ss.last;
ss.transition();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i in ss.as) {
```

You shouldn't use the `for...in` loop over an Array or, in this case, NodeList. You'll get member properties you don't want, like `item` and `length`. You also can't rely on the items being returned in any particular order; it is very likely that at least `ss.last` will not be what you expect. If it's a non-item property, `ss.old.style.display` will definitely fail with an exception, breaking the script.

The correct loop for a sequence is the old-school C construct:

```
for (var i= 0; i<ss.as.length; i++)
```

Also, where are you binding the calls to `goTo`? If you are doing it in a loop with a function inside you, you may well also have the classic loop closure problem. See eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562127/jquery-callback-function-only-working-on-last-loop).

Comment: This is wrong, the for works just fine and his problem is that the wrong elements are showing up for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the failure is because you lose the reference to the currently hidden element before you make it show up again.  You need to assign old to display:block, then do the switch of old = current, current = variable, then hide old.