# loop closure in jQuery

Tags: jquery, closures

The one without callback function [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xspG6/44/) produces wrong outcome. The console log should show i=0 & j=0 as indicated "group[0] record[0]". because I am trying to find the dd/dt set: "Book: a book name".

I understand I need to include a callback function similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562127/jquery-callback-function-only-working-on-last-loop). However I don't seem to understand how to insert the function correctly. Here is the one I am working on:

[jsfiddle w/ callback](http://jsfiddle.net/kFsa5/8/)

```
var arrDL = [];
$("dl").each(function(i) {     
   arrDL[i] = [];
   $(this).children("dt").each(function(j){ 
       function(n){
            return function(){
                var $this = $(this); 

                arrDL[n][j] = {
                   title: $this.text(),
                   description: $this.next("dd").text()
                };

                if($this.text() == "Book:" && $this.next("dd").text() == "another book name"){
                   console.log("group 0 record 0: " + n + '-' + j);
                };
           };    
      }(n);               
  });    
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a function inside the function (inside the callback for the inner `each`) and returning it. You are executing the outer function, but it returns a function reference which you don't execute, so the code inside the inner function will never run.

Also you are sending the variable `n` into the outer function, but it's never defined anywhere, so it will just be `undefined`.

Actually there is no need for either the outer or the inner function, just put the code in the callback for the `each`:

```
var arrDL = [];
$("dl").each(function(i) {     
  arrDL[i] = [];
  $(this).children("dt").each(function(j){ 
    var $this = $(this);
    arrDL[i][j] = {
      title: $this.text(),
      description: $this.next("dd").text()
    };
    if($this.text() == "Book:" && $this.next("dd").text() == "another book name"){
      console.log("group 0 record 0: " + i + '-' + j);
    };
  });    
});
```

The result that you get is correct, the description "another book name" is found in the second group, not the first group.

Comment: @user1824996: Yes, I arrived at the same code as in your fiddle when cleaning up the code in your question. :)