# Closure/callback in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

I have been trying to get this to work for a while and decided to just ask.

I have the following:

```
function doSomething(var1, var2) {
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url:"somUrl",
        content: {value1:var1,value2:var2},
        preventCache: true,
        handleAs:"json",
        load: function(response){
            for(var i in response.myObject) {
                var listItem = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
                    label: response.myObject[i].name,
                    rightText: response.myObject[i].value,
                    clickable: true, 
                    onClick: function() {
                        customFunction(response.myObject[i]);
                        this.transitionTo("someScreen");
                    }   
                });
                myList.addChild(listItem);
            }               
        },
        error:function(e){alert(e);}
    });
}
doSomething(myVal1, myVal2);
```

The line that says `customFunction(response.myObject[i]);` always returns the last object in the myObject arrray.

Can someone help me with the syntax so I can make this work correctly?  I've been reading about js closures and callbacks but I just can't get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of time by paying attention to the possible duplicate questions that Stackoverflow automatically shows you when you're trying to ask a new one. This issue in particular is covered by many many previous questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional wrapper function

```
onClick: (function(obj) {
    return function() {
        customFunction(obj);
        this.transitionTo("someScreen");
    };
})(response.myObject[i])
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables/643664#643664) for an explanation:

> JavaScript's scopes are function-level, not block-level, and creating
>   a closure just means that the enclosing scope gets added to the
>   lexical environment of the enclosed function.
>
> After the loop terminates, the function-level variable `i` has the
>   value `5` [**note:** *or, in this case, the name of the last property in* `response.myObject`], and that's what the inner function 'sees'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that `i` is contained in a closure in each iteration of the for-loop:

```
[...]
  load: function(response){
        for(var i in response.myObject) {
            var listItem = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
                label: response.myObject[i].name,
                rightText: response.myObject[i].value,
                clickable: true, 
                onClick: (function(inner) {
                    return function (clickEvent) {
                      customFunction(response.myObject[inner]);
                      this.transitionTo("someScreen");
                    }
                }(i))   
            });
            myList.addChild(listItem);
        }               
    }
 [...]
```

Comment: Now if only JS had better scoping options defined in the core language.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: "JS 1.7" has `let` blocks and statements

Comment: @newacct: it's also in the ES.next draft ( http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts ), ie the next ECMA edition will probably make it official...

Comment: @newacct - I am aware of `let` in JavaScript. What I should have said was ECMAScript. Logically you really can't use `let` unless you are targeting JavaScript only.