# closure in loop:variable declared in loop not being properly presetting into handler function, when bind an event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a logging function for automation unit test.

html elements structure:

```
<li> 
  <strong>
  <ol>
<li>
  <strong>
  <ol>
```

I want to make it when I click on the `<strong>`, the `<ol>` which under same `<li>` be toggle.

code:

```
for(var i = 0, l = logSuites.length; i < l; i++) {
        var suite = logSuites[i];
        $("#tests").append('<li><strong>....</strong></li>');
        var suiteSl = $('#tests > li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
        var caseli = "<li>...</li>...";
        ...
        suiteSl.append('<ol style="display:none">' + caseli + '</ol>');
        var caseLiSl = suiteSl.children('ol');
        var toggleCases = function() {
            caseLiSl.toggle();
        };
        suiteSl.children('strong').bind('click', toggleCases);
    }
```

the problem is everytime the event being triggered, the last `<ol>` be toggled.. The variable `caseLiSl` in function `toggleCases` is always the last time it settled in the `for` loop

Comment: A common problem with the powerful javascript closures

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That’s a more common problem. We use closures in a loop (for or while) and it always keep the last value of the increment.

Answer can be found in this question: [Doesn't JavaScript support closures with local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do

```
suiteSl.children('strong').bind('click', function(){
   $(this).children('ol').toggle();
});
```

in this way the `this` variable refers to the clicked element and you toggle only it's direct `<ol>` children

Comment: I may not be clear but <ol> isnot <strong> 's child but <li>'s.     `$(this).parent().children('ol').toggle();` works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is again the usual closure in a loop problem.

You probably should read this: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62