# On events in loop in dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set events to elements makes "on the fly", like `var X = $('HTML CODE HERE')`, but when I set the events to the last element, all other elements get this last event.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QmxX4/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ulItem = $('.lst');

    for (var x=0; x<5; x++) {

        var newItemElement = $('<li style="border:solid 1px blue;width:200px;height:40px;"></li>');
        ulItem.append(newItemElement);

        var generator = Math.random();
        newItemElement.on('click', function() {
            console.log(generator);  
        });

    }

});
```

All elements are diferents, and I attach the event in the element directly, im try to append before and after add event to element, but not work, all element get the last event.

If you make click in the `<li></li>` get code generated in the last event, but "in theory" all elements have diferent events attached..

But if I make other loop appending elements after append al items to `<ul></ul>`, like this:

```
$.each($(ulItem).children('li'), function(i, item) {
    console.log($(this));
    var generator = Math.random();
    $(this).on('click', function() {
         console.log(generator);
    });
});
```

Works... what is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doesn't JavaScript support closures with local variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables)

Comment: Thanks, little example of my problem here, i go to anonymous function to solve this problem. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first loop, the `generator` variable belongs to the `ready` callback function, and the inner log functions all share it.

In your second loop, the `generator` variable belongs to the `each` callback function which is called once for each item and therefore the log functions all see a different variable.

Comment: YES, this is the problem.. (to much hours working) thanks for the help!